# Cursor not visible in codeblocks after background color change?

Tags: codeblocks

I changed the background color of my code blocks editor to black, ever since I am not able to see my cursor, I tried to figure out which particular entity in settings->editor->syntax highlighting refers to a cursor, but to no avail, could you please tell me how to make the cursor show up again, I just need to know what it is called in code block jargon so that I can set its color to white.

Comment: @Nahkki, could you please tell me how to import themes into code blocks in ubuntu

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to *Settings->Editor->Margins and Caret*
Change the color of 'Caret' to whatever you would like your cursor to be

'Caret' isn't the name I would have expected either but, hey, it works.

Comment: another request though, how to import themes into code::blocks if you are running code blocks on ubuntu, there are a few videos on youtube but they are for windows

Comment: On Ubuntu, one can directly change the file `default.conf` which should be in `~/.config/codeblocks` or in `~/.codeblocks` by adding the wanted lines after `</default>`. A lot of possible editor themes are for example at http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Syntax_highlighting_custom_colour_themes#Solarized_Dark